# how to escape for mysql in asp.net?

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, security, ado.net

What's the ASP.NET equivalent of this PHP code?

```php
$db = new mysqli(/*some data*/);
$db->query('INSERT INTO `log` (`msg`) VALUES ("'.$db->real_escape_string($_POST['mesg']).'");');
```

Im only interested in `mysqli_real_escape_string`, but the only examples I can find on Google for ASP.NET and SQL *are all injectable*.

So my question is: How do I pass user data to SQL in ASP.NET using ADO.NET?

If you use replace of regex, please base your example on [this](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~libmysql-team/libmysql/1.0/view/head:/mysys/charset.c) code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using this approach, you'll want to look into using [parameterized SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx#paght000002_step3) in your code.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();

  SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Log WHERE Message = @Message", connection);                

  myCommand.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Message", SqlDbType.VarChar, 11);

  myCommand.SelectCommand.Parameters["@Message"].Value = messageString;

  myDataAdapter.Fill(userDataset);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the example. It's for SQL Server, but the MySQL connector has corresponding classes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use properties if possible. Then you don't need to escape the strings yourself.

If you can't do that, you need to escape both backslashes and apostrophes:

```
public static string EscapeForMySQL(string str) {
  return str.Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("'", "\\'")
}
```

Comment: @borrel: What do you mean? In what way is it not good enough?

Comment: there are a lot of known attacks for this kind of methodes, there is a generic methode (like real_escape_string) whitch sould be used, this is why i includet the example, in other words yes this is a solution, but it is no THE way to go

Comment: @borrel: The generic method is to use parameters, just as I mentioned first of all in the answer. It doesn't exist any method in the framework to escape a string for any SQL dialect.

Comment: eee its still not safe!!, what can you do with # and newline for example!!

Comment: -1 for giving me insecure code while i specifically asked for securety, also this can break multibyte(unicode/utf)

Comment: @borrel: The `#` character has no special meaning in a string literal, and putting newline characters in a string literal is not a problem. A string is Unicode, if you want to encode it, you should do that after escaping it. You are escaping characters, not bytes.

Comment: true but it might not be literal also can be int then there are no quotes

Comment: @borrel: You should not encode an int as if it was a string literal. You should simply make sure that it's actually an int, then it can't contain any harmful characters.

Answer (score 0):

If possible please refactor to avoid dynamic sql or use parameterized queries.

Use Parameterized queries for ODBC (I believe in oledbcommand will work here as well)

http://weblogs.asp.net/cumpsd/archive/2004/04/05/107456.aspx

See my talk on it - its the first subject:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/DEV333